# Haskell Finite Byte

Tags: haskell, instance

I am using haskell to write a Defition of byte in combination with a definition of finite to create an occurrence of a finite byte.

This is what I have so far:

```
module Foldables where

import Prelude hiding (Applicative(..), any, concat)
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Semigroup

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Map.Append (AppendMap(..))
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.Maybe (maybe)
import Data.Monoid (Any(..), Sum(..))
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

class Finite (a :: *) where
   -- exists n. length elements == n
   -- forall x. elem x elements == True
   elements :: [a]

 instance Finite Bool where
   elements = [True, False]

-- The type "Either a b" is finite when both "a" and "b" are finite.


 instance (Finite a, Finite b) => Finite (Either a b) where
   elements = fmap Left elements ++ fmap Right elements

-- Similarly, the type "(a,b)" is finite when both "a" and "b" are finite.

 instance (Finite a, Finite b) => Finite (a, b) where
   elements = allPairs elements elements


 data Byte = Bits Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool
   deriving (Generic, Eq, Show)
```

I'm just stuck on this last line:

```
instance Finite Byte where
   elements = undefined
```

The instructions say to give a Finite instance for the Byte type.
Do not use the True and False constructors explicitly in your definition.

(Hint: use the list monad or a list comprehension.)

Please don't change anything other than what's left undefined.

*Update*

This worked:

```
instance Finite Byte where
   elements = Bits <$> elements <*> elements <*> elements <*> elements <*> elements <*> elements <*> elements <*> elements
```

Comment: hint: `[minBound .. maxBound]` gives `False` and `True`. You can make use of `<$>` and `<*>` to construct all possible `Byte`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think in this case, there's a custom `Finite` class and instance defined for `Bool`s that should be used instead.

Comment: byteToInt :: Byte -> Int
 byteToInt (Bits x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2 x1 x0) =
   sum [bitToInt x * 2^n | (x,n) <- zip [x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7] [0..7]]
   where
     bitToInt :: Bool -> Int
     bitToInt False = 0
     bitToInt True = 1
  (I also have this; should I be using it here?)

Comment: @steve: I don't think this is necessary no.

Comment: Hint: look at (and adapt) the implementation of `allPairs`.

Comment: i see that elements is used as the arguments for allPairs, but would I just use Byte in the place of allPairs? @DanielWagner

Comment: @steve No, you would look at (and adapt) the implementation of `allPairs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) and [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-). To construct a list of all values of `Byte`.

For example if you make a data type `Nibble`:

```
data Nibble = Nibble Bool Bool Bool Bool
```

You can obtain a list of all possible `Nibble`s with `Nibble <$> [False, True] <*> [False, True] <*> [False, True] <*> [False, True]`. This thus will be `[Nibble False False False False, Nibble False False False True, …, Nible True True True True]`.

If you thus make `Bool` an instance of `Finite`, like [@Aplet123 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459933/haskell-finite-byte#comment112216393_63459933), then you can make use of `elements` to obtain the list of values for `Bool`, and then define an instance for `Byte`:

```
instance Finite Bool where
    elements = [False, True]

instance Finite Byte where
    elements = …  -- with Byte, <$>, <*> and elements
```

where you fill in `…` based on the way we can define this for `Nibble`.

Comment: so the syntax is: Elements = Nibble <$> [False, True] <*> [False, True] <*> [False, True] <*> [False, True]   ??

Comment: @steve: that is for a `Nibble` (with four bits). You need to generalize it to `Byte`. This is furthermore no *syntax*, `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` are simply functions.

Comment: The assignment says, I'm not to use True and False constructors explicitly

Comment: @steve: you don't. As said, you already have these, these are the `elements` of the `Finite Bool` instance, so you can use these in the definition of the `elements` of `Finite Byte`, as is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: ah I see, so I did elements = [Bits False False False False False False False False, Bits False False False False False False False True, …, Bits True True True True True True True]
Only trouble is I get a parsing error with those commas

Comment: @steve: but you should not define the list yourself. You simply alter the `Nible <$> ...` expression to work with `Byte`, and instead of using `[False, True]`, you can use `elements`.

Comment: So, Byte elements elements elements elements elements elements elements elements ??

Comment: @steve: yes, but with `<$>` and `<*>` although that might be StackOverflow that does not formats it correctly since you did not use a coding environment.

Comment: elements = Byte <$> [elements] <*> [elements] <*> [elements] <*> [elements] <*> [elements] <*> [elements]           Gives me: Data constructor not in scope:
      Byte
        :: [a7]
           -> [a6] -> [a5] -> [a4] -> [a3] -> [a2] -> [a1] -> [a0] -> Byte

Comment: @steve: sorry the data constructor of your `Byte` is `Bits`, so `Bits <$> ...`.

Comment: I did try that already, and I got:  • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[a0]’ for each of the 8 elements

Comment: @steve: but it is not `[elements]` but `elements`, since `elements` will already collapse to `[Bool]`...